# how to set query to be read uncommited?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

with hibernate, how can I set a query to be read uncommitted? 
I don't want this to be a global setting, just want to do it on a per query basis.

Comment: do you manage your transactions manually, or using sprig/EJB

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization (which Is The Root Of All Evil). Do you currently have a real problem?

Answer (score 6):

Using Spring with Hibernate it is possible to have Spring controlling transactions with annotations, that is some configuration like the one below in spring applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- To use annotation driven in aspect mode (mode="aspectj"), it is necessary to add spring-aspects lib -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

The best way to achieve that is to using an annotation like the one below:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `session.connection().setTransactionIsolation(...)`?

P.S. For modern [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control)-based DBMS you don't need to use "read uncomitted" to avoid locks. Some DBMS even don't have this isolation level implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Set the transaction isolation level:

```
session.connection().setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
```

Answer (score 2):

The Hibernate API itself provides no way to do this programmatically, that I'm aware of. The docs do say that you can specify the isolation level as a configuration property:

> **hibernate.connection.isolation** - Sets
>   the JDBC transaction isolation level.
>   Check java.sql.Connection  for
>   meaningful values

But of course this applies to the whole `SessionFactory`, not just to specific queries.

It's tempting to fiddle with the underlying `java.sql.Connection` isolation level, but I'd be very careful about doing that sort of thing, you run the risk of conflicting with hibernate's own locking strategies, which use the JDBC isolation level to determine which `LockMode` will be used. If you change this directly on the Connection, you might get odd results. You may not have a choice, of course, but be careful.

A "better" solution would be to use [Spring's Hibernate Transaction API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-hibernate-tx-programmatic), which allows you to decouple the transaction semantics like isolation level from the Hibernate API completely, in a predictable and reliable way.

Answer (score 0):

by default, statements are not committed in hibernate until you do it explicitly (or the connection is returned to the pool and the driver happens to do a commit for you, which isn't guaranteed). so, it seems to do what you want already.

you can also just rollback the current transaction if you want to nullify the statements made since the beginning of the transaction.

in mysql, you could do something like:

```
set session transaction isolation level read uncommitted
```

or use the method [axtavt suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015903/how-to-set-query-to-be-read-uncommited/2016059#2016059),

call [getTransactionIsolation()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getTransactionIsolation()) before the query to get the current mode so you can put it back after the stmt if you like.